# Fatal error: Class 'AppioLab\LRPC\Lrpc' not found in CodeIgniter when using in DigitalOcean

Tags: php, codeigniter, composer-php, digital-ocean

I am using Composer with CodeIgniter in a Vagrant machine. My development environment is CentOS 6.5, PHP 5.6. I've loaded my other package from github through `composer.json` and in my development environment everything working fine. When I loaded the full folder in my DigitalOcean VPS and try to run the application, I got this fatal error:

`Fatal error: Class 'AppioLab\LRPC\Lrpc' not found in /var/www/html/personal/demo/lstoxero/public_html/application/controllers/mytest.php on line 43`

Line 43 is where I am trying to create an instance of Class I've loaded through composer and autoload.php

This is my folder structure
[image]

This is my Test Controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


    use AppioLab\LRPC\Lrpc;

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    class MyTest extends CI_Controller {

        public function test(){

            echo "Cron Test<br>";
            $lrpc = new Lrpc(); // this is line 43 in my code.
            echo "lrpc loadedt<br>";
        }

    }
```

When I try to access this test function with url `http://mydemosite.com/MyTest/test` I get the error I mention above. What I am doing wrong and why is it running in Vagrant but not in live which is also CentOS 6.5?

Comment: which CodeIgniter version are you using? think that it doesn't support namespaces and need a workaround for that to work

Comment: @Kstro21 I am using Version 2.2.1. This is working perfect in my Vagrant with CentOS 6.5, But when I upload in my DigitalOcean VPS, it breaks. Can't figure whats missing here

Comment: If you use namespaces php version must be >= 5.3.0

Comment: @Kstro21 In my development, I've PHP 5.5.16 and in my Live I've PHP 5.3.3

Comment: Seems you have one more folder inside `AppioLab\LRPC\Lrpc` path?